# Адаптивная верстка при фиксированном размере блока

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

У меня есть `<div>` блоки, которые обязательно должны иметь фиксированную ширину. Я пытаюсь подстроить дизайн под *iphone 5*, я знаю ширину экрана мобильного браузера и делаю блок ширины под него, но он сильно уменьшается в мобильном браузере, как будто запускается под разрешение ПК и остается белый кусок справа. Как можно сделать так, чтобы блок на телефоне был во всю ширину экрана и в ПК версии он имел такую же ширину, как и в мобильной?

```css
div{
  background:  red;
  height:  50px;
  width:  300px;
}
```

```html
<div>Внутренности блока</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо в head'e прописать строку:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Тогда на мобильных устройствах всё будет ок.

Comment: Спасиб большое!

Comment: если ответ Вам помог, отметьте его галкой

Comment: Конечно, после прохождения временного запрета на принятие :)